# Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly in python 3.4.3

Tags: python

I am new in the world of programming. I have just started python 3.4.3. here i tried to write :

```
>>> A = input ("number :")
number :10
>>> A + 1
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       A + 1 TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

Waiting for your help. TIA ... :)

Comment: This is not specific to python 3.4.3. Edit - Python 3.2 also shows this behavior. Is it so much trouble to just use int()?

Comment: Hint! Check what is type of A by entering type(A) and see if it's string or int and then you can cast it accordingly

Comment: @kilojoules , python 2.7 input is already and int value..

Comment: >>> int(A) + 1 works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast:

```
A = int(input("number :"))
```

`input` returns a string in python 3.